# Why it is required to write each byte with 0 before erase in NOR flash?

Tags: memory, flash, non-volatile-memory, flash-memories, nand-flash

It is written in some sites that for NOR flash, each byte has to be written with 0 before erase. Why it is required to write with 0 before erasing? Erasing the sector change each byte to 1.

Comment: Link............

Comment: Can you provide some links from those websites so that we have more context of what you're talking about? [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_memory#NOR_flash) might be able to answer your question.

Comment: Isn't this just from a security perspective, because flash doens't actually overwrite during an erase, and just marks that bank as 'empty'?

Comment: https://www.embedded.com/flash-101-nand-flash-vs-nor-flash/

Comment: https://www.elinfor.com/knowledge/what-is-on-earth-the-difference-between-nand-flash-and-nor-flash-1-p-11163

Comment: those two links are duplicate articles